# Reload WebView from Menu Item (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, webview, webkit

I want to reload a `WebView` whenever a certain menu item is clicked. Here's my code that's not working. (Assume normal declarations in `.h` files.)

---

```
// AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
// #import "ViewController.h" (in AppDelegate.h)

@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  // Insert code here to initialize your application
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

// Menu Item triggers this:
- (IBAction)reloadWebView:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"AppDelegate reloadWebView");
  ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
  [vc reloadWebView:sender]; // tried this,
  [vc.webview reload:sender]; // and this,
  [[vc.webview mainFrame] reload]; // and this,
  [[vc.webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]]]; // and this.
}

@end
```

---

```
// ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

// @property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webview; (in ViewController.h)

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webview;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]]]; // this works
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
  [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
  // Update the view, if already loaded.
}

// Called in AppDelegate:
- (void)reloadWebView:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"ViewController reloadWebView");
  // The problem here seems to be: webview == nil
  [webview reload:sender]; // also tried this,
  [[webview mainFrame] reload]; // and this,
  [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]]]; // and this.
}

@end
```

---

This is all my code. I've just started working on this project.

I've tried using a button in the `ViewController`. That works, but I need this to be a menu item.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check to see if `webview` is not nil, you probably forgot to make the outlet for the WebView in the Interface builder or it's configured incorrectly.

Comment: @ecnepsnai Ah, you're right! `webview == nil`. Any advice on how to get the right `webview`? `self.webview == nil` as well.

Comment: Are you using the interface builder, or making the webview pragmatically?

Comment: @ecnepsnai Interface Builder: `@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webview;`

Comment: Try using `(weak, nonatomic)`, but also check to see that there is a relationship between that line in your header file and the webview by right clicking the webview in the interface builder.

Comment: @ecnepsnai That didn't work, but I tried changing the trigger to a button instead of a menu item. That fixed it. I'll rephrase my question, and if I figure this out myself I'll post an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a new view controller:

```
    ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

try:

```
    ViewController * vc = (ViewController *)[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentViewController];
```

to call the current view controller